# Open Source OS alternative for Windows Server 2003

Tags: linux, windows, opensuse

**Problem**

I am using Windows server 2003 SE. And as heard Microsoft will not provide support for windows server 2003 anymore.

**Looking for**

I want to migrate to a open source server OS which will be proper replacement for the server. Only one thing comes to my mind is Linux, but there are different distributions of Linux, like Red Hat, ubuntu, Cent OS, SlackWare, SUSE and many more. Among them few have only enterprise version of Linux Server. I am not quite sure to go with which open source server. If any other linux distribution is suitable, then also you please suggest.

**More**

The need is not for very big organization rather it's for mid-size company with around 1000 students. Along with Essential features of server i need to have LDAP, CVS and dhcp, file server, printer server and similar packages.

Comment: What kind of software should run on the server, i.e. Samba, Database etc.? See this [book](http://debian-handbook.info/) to learn, how Debian will be administrated.

Comment: Along with Essential features of server i need to have LDAP, CVS and dhcp, file server, printer server and similar packages.

Comment: do you mean obviously? You should put your software requirements in the question.

Comment: It would be nice if you defined what you mean with "Essential". What you've listed so far is available on any Unix system - including Linux, but also FreeBSD and the other BSDs, Illumos (formerly OpenSolaris) etc.

Comment: I'd say, try [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) out. The distribution has a long tradition and is often used as a server OS. The book, I've mentioned in my first comment, covers the most topics you need.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my basic rule of thumb when choosing an OS for... well, pretty much anything, really.

- What will run on it? Are there any specific applications requiring any specific OS, that can't be replaced with something else? If so, choose what supports the things you need.
- What support structure is needed? Do you need to have a support organization that you can call up? If so, choose an OS that is offered commercially (e.g. RedHat or SUSE)
- Who will manage it? What skills do they have? Do they have a favourite OS that they are very familiar with? If so, choose that.

Basically, if you don't have any particular technical reason to choose a specific OS, then go with what the people who will work with it are most comfortable with. But you need to think through all the specifics to be sure what technical reasons to choose otherwise may apply, and there's not enough information in the post to help with that.

Comment: Thanks @Jenny for the reply. We have experts in Linux/windows. How about Ubuntu server? Even they have commercial support. Is it good to go with open source servers, which might charge for commercial support, instead of Windows OS.